# Android Fragment Data from 1 activity to list in another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2 activities 1 is main activity which has 2 fragments left and right and I have 1 more activity Signup which has some fields in it.
I need to submit that form and that details should be saved in a list in the 1st activity left fragment.

Screenshots:

- [Main activity with 2 fragments left and right](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OIhWnXnuKmH2D-X-wRVAMXYvEoLIdWNA/view?usp=sharing)
- [Signup form](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymTjiikgS9_1BIo9nWQHFEPGhKhXS-85/view?usp=sharing)
- [After submitting the form the left fragment of activity 1 should look like that enter image description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KhW856vqZqYvbfZV78wcsbmNxeVUZPZM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please, try to explain what do you want more clear. Actually, we don't need screenshots if it is not UI problem. Say which activity is first, what app have to do step by step and what is going wrong when you tried to implement it.

Comment: FIrstly I am in Main Activity 
There I have a button through which Second activity opens i.e., Signup 
At the Signup Activity i Need to fill the details and click save @H.Taras
After doing that the data should be stored in a list and that list should be displayed in a fragment

Comment: And you want to pass this details to second activity, right?

Comment: No in 1st activity but that activity is divided into 2 fragments left and right i need to send it to left 1 . Please have a look at attached files u vl get the idea

Comment: can you update your fragment activity??i mean 2 activity which is holds 2 fragments!

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you want to display data in list in Activity A's LeftFragment. The data which is filled by user on Activity B(Sign up).

Here are the steps you need to perform

1. Perform the click event of button and use `startActivityForResult()`
2. On your Activity B (Sign Up) collect the data and `finish` Activity B
   using `setResult()` and `finish()`
3. You will receive a data in your Activity A inside `onActivityResult()`
4. Now using interface you need to pass that data to your Left fragment
   using simple delegation
5. Once you receive data in Left `Fragment` show as you want.

Comment back if you are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try My suggestion :

In your MainActiivty Pass your Data through intent like:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("status", name);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And inside your First Fragment class:

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calldialclass, container, false);
            String status = null;
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null)
                status = bundle.getString("status");
            yourTextviewReference.setText(status); 
}
```

i hope this is helpfull to you.Let me know is this working or not.